# Корни с чередованием

Tags: орфография

"Равняйсь! Иванов,подр*вняй ряды!" С одной стороны, смысл тот же, что и в "равняйсь",т.е. пишем через "а", но чувствую тут какой-то подвох...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Равняйсь! - корень РАВН со значением "равный, **одинаковый**", это команда встать **одинаково** с фланговым.

Подровнять ряды - корень РОВН со значением "ровный, плавный, гладкий, без отклонений", это команда **выровнять линию** (сделать ровной линию, сделать гладкой поверхность, ровный характер, ровный ход машины и т.д.)

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но разыскав оригинал этой фразы у Бека, видим в обоих словах «а».

Answer (score 5):

> "Равняйсь! Иванов, подр*вняй ряды!" С одной стороны, смысл тот же, что
>   и в "равняйсь", т.е. пишем через "а", но чувствую тут какой-то
>   подвох...

И правильно чувствуете!

Традиционная формулировка правила написания корней ***равн-*** и ***ровн-*** основана на различении значений корней. Корню ***равн-*** приписывают значение *"равный, одинаковый"*, корню ***ровн-*** -- значение *"ровный, прямой, гладкий".*

То, что ***"Равняйсь!"*** пишется с ***"а"***, нужно просто запомнить: это слово относится к словам с неясной смысловой соотнесённостью.

Что же до ***подр*вняй***...

У Асеева в *подр*вняй* [в издании 1956 года](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1Z9HAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y)  стоит ***"о"***:

> *Встань, раздайся и постройся, **подровняй** свои ряды, огляди свое геройство, даль зрачками обведи.*

[В издании 1964 года](https://books.google.ru/books?id=rW0jAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y)  -- ***"а"***:

> *Встань, раздайся и постройся, **подравняй** свои ряды, огляди свое геройство, даль зрачками обведи.*

В пособии для подготовки к ЕГЭ в 2015 году -- тоже ***"а"***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как правильно?

Оказывается, оба варианта правильны.

См. ***Бешенкова Е.В., Иванова О.Е., Чельцова Л.К. "Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник", М., 2015***:

> **ПОДРАВНЯТЬ**… закрепившееся написание в слове с неясной смысловой соотнесённостью.
>
> Напр... ***подравнять строй***, подравнять края; в этих же контекстах
>   может быть и глагол ***подровнять***.

Answer (score 2):

Эти два слова различаются значением.

Первое - рАвнять - означает становиться в строю на одну прямую линию с фланговым.

РОвнять - делать ровным, гладким, например: выстраиваться ровной, прямой линией.

См. [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/47565/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).

```
Я скомандовал: — Равняйсь! Ползунов, подровняй ряды! Смирно! Бек, Волоколамское шоссе.
```